# vs2010 plugin C# to VB.net en VB.net to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

does anyone know if there is a plugin that makes it available to make visual studio language independend? So when I "push" a button I can see and edit the code in C# or in VB.net? I would be ok if I cant use all language specific options.

Comment: For what I know a button is put over a form or control, which is included in a project that is created from user choosing developing language... so I think it's not possible to do what you're asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unaware of any pluggin. But are you looking for feature like this http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: yeah, but then as a VS2010 plugin. Not sure if it exists.

Comment: I am sure it doesnot exist atleast as a free plugin